# The 50 Move Rule

Tags: rules, draw, 50-move-rule

Can the fifty move counter be increased after white's move?
I thought that it could only be increased if both white and then black had not moved a pawn nor captured a piece that qualified for a whole move. The reason I ask is that the other day while playing against a chess engine, after white moved, the engine sent the 50 move violation message, where as my count was 49 until black's move.

Answer (score 6):

[Fide Laws of Chess](https://www.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=171&view=article)

> 5.2 e. The game may be drawn if each player has made at least the last 50 moves without the movement of any pawn and without any capture (see Article 9.3).
>
> 9.3 The game is drawn, upon a correct claim by a player having the move, if: [...]
> b. the last 50 moves by each player have been completed without the movement of any pawn and without any capture.

So it doesn't matter who is black and who is white. If the last pawn move or capture was made by white, the rule comes into effect after white's move.

Comment: Thanks JiK !  I'll need to re-program my fifty count routine to reflect this :)